# Access variable Array Data PHP

Tags: php, arrays, facebook

i have the following Array Structure from Facebook Graph API response.

```
  "data": [
    {
      "actions": [
        {
          "action_type": "comment",
          "value": "2"
        },
        {
          "action_type": "offsite_conversion",
          "value": "1606"
        }
      ],
      "date_start": "2017-04-03",
      "date_stop": "2017-05-02"
    },
    {
      "actions": [

        {
          "action_type": "post",
          "value": "2"
        },
        {
          "action_type": "post_reaction",
          "value": "33"
        },
        {
          "action_type": "page_engagement",
          "value": "816"
        },
        {
          "action_type": "post_engagement",
          "value": "807"
        },
        {
          "action_type": "offsite_conversion",
          "value": "1523"
        }
      ],
      "date_start": "2017-04-03",
      "date_stop": "2017-05-02"
    },
]
```

The Number of values is flexible and i want to get the value from "offsite_conversion". Normally i would do it for example like that:

```
data['data'][0]['actions']['1']['value']
```

But in that case this doesn't work because ['1'] is variable.

Comment: And what is the problem to replace `'1'` with a variable?

Comment: could you please give me more details. so i had allready the idea to count the numbers of 'actions' because "offsite_conversions" is always the last and then calculate the '1'

Comment: There are multiple instances of offsite_conversion. Which one are you trying to get? Or are you trying to get them all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a loop and test the action type.

```
foreach ($data['data'][0]['actions'] as $action) {
    if ($action['action_type'] == 'offsite_conversion') {
        $result = $data['value'];
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> because "offsite_conversions" is always the last

If `$data['data'][0]['actions'][LAST VALUE]['value']` is what you're looking for:

Your idea of counting should work then:

```
$actions = $data['data'][0]['actions'];
$index = count($actions) - 1;

$value = $actions[$index]['value'];
```

Comment: Kind of recreating a built-in function here.

Comment: I wouldn't rely on it always being last. Assuming the order is fixed is usually a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

So not completely clear what are you trying to achieve, but in a simple way you can just iterate over your `$data` array:

```
$needed_values = array();
foreach ($data['data'] as $item) {
    foreach ($item['actions'] as $action) {
        if ($action['action_type'] == 'offsite_conversion') {
            $needed_values[] = $action['value'];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretend `$json` holds the data from facebook

```
<?php
$data = json_decode($json);
$conversions = 0;
foreach ($data as $datum) {
  foreach ($datum['actions'] as $action) {
    if ($action['action_type'] === 'offsite_convserion') {
      $conversions += (int)$action['value'];
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Second `foreach` is over `$datum['actions']`

Comment: Thank you @u_mulder

Answer (score 0):

[Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) has the best approach if you don't know where it is, but it's much easier if you want the last one:

```
$result = end($data['data'][0]['actions'])['value'];
```